# Email Alert in Workflow rule for order

Tags: workflow

I have created a new custom setting field on the custom settings, i want to access the custom field of  name to address for accessing the email template in workflow rule how? for to address field in the email template for workflow rule

Email alert recipient based on custom settings of field stored on to address there?

**How to access the to adress custom setting field in the email alert recipent for work flow rule**

Please anyone guide me for the answer

How to access the stored email address field in the email alert recipent type

Answer (score 0):

If this is Hierarchical Type custom setting then you can easily refer that

```
 {!$Setup.SomeCustomSetting__c.SomeField__c}
```

If this is a List type custom setting then it's not possible to use that in email template. You need to send Email from Apex. Or you can create a Hierarchical CS (if not already using that).

I don't think you can refer Custom setting in recipient field in Email Alert. But You can use this template and send the email using Apex code

Comment: In Recipent type i want to access there? is it possible email alert in workflow rule @tushar sharma

Comment: please explain You need to use VF Email template or need to send Email from Apex. Or you can create a Hierarchical CS> for this scenario

Comment: How to access the custom field in recipent type of Email alert in workflow rule

Comment: I want to access in the  {!$Setup.SomeCustomSetting__c.SomeField__c} in Recipent box of Email alert in workflow rule  How?

Comment: i am using vf email template only, and Hierarchy custom type only,can you please explain ellaborately,iwant to access in Recipent type box in Email alert @tushar sharma